# gitlab Cypress generate allure report

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, cypress, pipeline, allure

I have my .gitlab-ci.yml file as follows:

```
image: cypress/base:14.16.0

stages:
  - test
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run scripts
```

where scripts is --> `cypress run  --spec cypress/integration/UI/myScript.feature`

when adding another command after the scripts parameter to generate allure report, The gitlab pipeline is throwing me an error of JAVA home path not being set to generate allure report.

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH
```

So I updated my script to something like this:

```
image: cypress/base:14.16.0

stages:
  - test
  - allure

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run clean:allure
    - npm run scripts

allure_report:
  stage: allure
  when: always
  image: timbru31/java-node
  dependencies: 
    - test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run generate-allure-report
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - cypress/reportsAllure/allure-report/
      - cypress/reportsAllure/allure-results/
```

where generate-allure-report is --> `allure generate cypress/reportsAllure/allure-results --clean -o cypress/reportsAllure/allure-report`

But here empty reports are generated. does anyone know what artifacts I need to pass from the first stage onto next in order to generate allure report ?

Comment: What is the error? I also recommend having `npm install` as one step and `npm run scripts` as another, separation makes it a bit more understandable in my opinion.

Comment: I get an error that JAVAHOME is not set. Meaning allure needs to have Java in the image it’s being run on. So how to use 2 images in .yml ?

Comment: I've run into this article they have slightly different approach to preserving the allure data with the trends... https://medium.com/testvagrant/generating-allure-trendline-on-gitlab-pages-df01c8798ae2

Comment: you could move also move the `image: cypress/base:14.16.0` into the `test:` as that stage doesn't need any java , the allure-results are happening thanks to the npm package you are using, but `allure_report:` requires the image with java + allure installed (and I can't see any attempts of installing allure, so hard to understand how would you turn the allure-results > allure-report) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, but I'm using the default folder locations so you'd need to change those same as artifacts paths and append `-o folder/allure-report` where appropriate

```
stages:
  - test
  - allure
  - deploy

cache:
  key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - node_modules

.download_history: &download_history
  after_script:
    - apt-get install -y unzip
    - mkdir backup && cd backup || true
    - "curl --location --output report.zip --request GET \"https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=pages\" --header \"Authorization: Bearer ${CI_DEPLOY_TOKEN}\" || true"
    - (unzip report.zip) || true
    - cd ../
    - (cp -r backup/public/history/ allure-results/history/) || true


.test_template: &test_template
  image: 
    name: cypress/included:7.5.0
    entrypoint: [""]
  stage: test
  variables:
    CY_RUN_ID: ${CI_JOB_ID}
  script:
    - export CYPRESS_VIDEO=false
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/.bin/cypress run --headless --env allure=true
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - allure-results/

smoke:
  <<: *test_template
  <<: *download_history

allure_report:
  stage: allure
  when: always
  image: 
    name: ubuntu:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  dependencies: 
    - smoke
  variables:
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND: noninteractive
    TZ: Europe/London
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install -y default-jdk wget unzip 
    - mkdir /work/
    - wget https://github.com/allure-framework/allure2/releases/download/2.13.8/allure-2.13.8.zip -P /work/
    - unzip /work/allure-2.13.8.zip -d /work/
  script:
    - /work/allure-2.13.8/bin/allure generate allure-results --clean -o allure-report
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - allure-report/
      - allure-results/
  only:
    - master

pages:
  stage: deploy
  when: always
  dependencies:
    - allure_report
  script:
    - mv allure-report/ public/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
    expire_in: 30 days
  only:
    - master
```